# Storing specific Contacts on iPhone without syncing

Tags: iphone, contacts, accounts, privacy

I would like to store specific contacts on my iPhone, running iOS 7, without syncing them to *any* service.

I do have an Exchange account for business contacts but don't want do sync all contacts with the exchange server. I searched the web for a while but there does not seem to be any way to have local contacts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the sync for iCloud and every mail account :

- Settings

  - iCloud
  - Mail, Contacts, Calendar

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After deactivating syncing with all services I was able to create a local contact which seems not to be sync after turning sync on for the exchange account (leaving it deactivated is not an option). This leads to two follow-ups "How can I decide if a contact should be synced with the exchange account or not on creation?" and  "How can I distinguish a synced from a non-synced contact from the contact details?"

Comment: In order to determine which account a contact is synced to upon creation, you need to change the default contacts account on your iPhone. Go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars and tap Default account under Contacts. To distinguish synced from local contacts, enter the Contacts app and tap "Groups" on the top left.

Comment: @jDonMas thanks for your comment, I hoped for an easier way, I was hoping to be able to determine that from the contact details

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Default contacts account on the iPhone. This way you can choose where newly-created contacts to be saved (local iPhone memory or cloud account such as Exchange).

Alternatively, you can add contact entries to the local memory without needing to fickle with the iPhone settings via this method: [How to import contacts to iPhone](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-import-contacts-to-iphone/).